ACS Hang up from the server does not make the client leave
I want to set up Azure communication services to handle video conference on my app.
Right now I create a groupCall so that I can use call automation on the call. Room calls aren't supported by call automation, I understand why but it seems to be this way.
From the client side I can join the group call, display the other users, mute, basic stuff.
Now, I wan't to be able to kick everyone in the room if the server detects that the master of the room left. The webhooks are setup so I do catch the "Microsoft.Communication.CallParticipantRemoved" event, i can then get the user and try to hang up for everyone if the master left. The issue is that users don't get kicked.
I tried await callConnection.hangUp(true), this function doesn't trigger any errors and when I try to get the properties of the room I can't because the room doesn't exist anymore but on the client side nothing happens, the users are still in the room.
I also tried await callConnection.removeParticipant(participant.identifier) but I get this error {"code":"8501","details":{"error":{"code":"8501","message":"Action is invalid when call is not in Established state"}}, ... }  even though the call is running
Also I don't understand why I can join any groupId that I want from the client as long as it is a valid GUID, just by using the token that I generated from the server. If the user knew the GUID of another room he could join it and that would not be secure except if I could detect him from the server and kick him after he joined.
Maybe the user joins a groupId from the client and the server has a call automation on the same groupId BUT they are not in sync, not the same "instance". I say that because when I hang up a call on the server, I can't load the properties of the call because it's deleted which makes sense. On the client though I the users don't get kicked and they can still join that call with the same groupId. But they can join any groupId as long as it is a valid GUID.
Anyways I don't understand what's going, do you guys have any insights ?

Here is some code that I use :
Generate the token
const generateToken = async (communicationUserId?: string) => {
    let CommunicationUserIdentifier

    const identityClient = new CommunicationIdentityClient(
        envConfig.AZURE_COMMUNICATION_SERVICE_CONNECTION_STRING
    )

    if (!communicationUserId) {
        CommunicationUserIdentifier = await identityClient.createUser()
        console.log(`\nCreated an identity with ID: ${CommunicationUserIdentifier.communicationUserId}`)
    } else {
        CommunicationUserIdentifier = {
            communicationUserId: communicationUserId
        }
        console.log(`\nIdentity used is ID: ${CommunicationUserIdentifier.communicationUserId}`)
    }

    // Issue an access token with a validity of 24 hours and the "voip" scope for an identity
    let tokenResponse = await identityClient.getToken(CommunicationUserIdentifier, ['voip'])

    // Get the token and its expiration date from the response
    const { token, expiresOn } = tokenResponse
    console.log(`\nIssued an access token with 'voip' scope that expires at ${expiresOn}:`)

    return token
}

To create the groupCall
const groupCall = await callAutomationClient.createGroupCall(
            [
                {
                    communicationUserId: acsUserId
                }
            ],
            `${envConfig.SERVER_URL}/callback`
        )
        const acsCallId = (await groupCall.callConnection.getCallConnectionProperties()).callConnectionId!

I then pass the value of acsCallId and the generated token to the client and connect using those
const credential = new AzureCommunicationTokenCredential(generatedToken);
const callClient = new CallClient();
callAgent = await callClient.createCallAgent(credential);
call = callAgent.join({ groupId: acsCallId }, callOptions);

Then on back on the server I don't manage to make it work as I want when I use
const callConnection = callAutomationClient.getCallConnection(callId)
await callConnection.hangUp(true)


Please share the code you tried in the above question in text format.

Hello, I updated the question to add some more code that I use

The error message {"code":"8501","details":{"error":{"code":"8501","message":"Action is invalid when call is not in Established state"}}} indicates that the removeParticipant method is being called while the call is not in the "Established" state. This  happens if the call is still in the process of being set up or if it's already been terminated.
You can check the call state or waiting for the appropriate event.
const createCallEventResult : CreateCallEventResult = await callResult.waitForEventProcessor(undefined, 30000);

if (createCallEventResult.isSuccess)
{
  const callConnectedEvent : CallConnected = createCallEventResult.successResult!;
}
else{
}



From this MSDOC  Azure Communication Services Call Automation capabilities currently don't support Rooms call.
Callback events are events sent back during duration of the call. It gives information and state of the call, such as CallConnected. CallbackUrl must be provided during createCall and answerCall, and callback events will be sent to this url.

Make to use outbound call ,Connect to an ongoing call and Answer an incoming call .
Refer this  MSDOC to add group calls on Azure Communication Services

const callbackUri = "https://<myendpoint>/Events"; 

async function createGroupCall() {
    try {
        const response = await client.createGroupCall(participants, callbackUri, createCallOptions);
        const callConnection = response.callConnection;
        
        console.log("Group call created successfully. Call connection ID:", callConnection.connectionId);

        return callConnection;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to create group call:", error);
    }
}


async function hangUpCall(callConnection) {
    try {
        await callConnection.hangUp(true);
        console.log("Call hung up successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to hang up the call:", error);
    }
}
async function main() {
    const callConnection = await createGroupCall();
    if (callConnection) {
        await hangUpCall(callConnection);
    }
}


Output:

